# BreezeJS/Odata - metadata location/url

Tags: odata, breeze

In our odata service implementation, the autogenerated metadata can be accessed at:

```
https://<ourserver>/v1/$metadata
```

But the BreezeJS tries to access it from `https://<ourserver>/v1/Metadata`.  And it gets a 404 error as the metadata is not served at this location.

How to instruct BreezeJs to find the metadata at any given URL?

The code `entityManger.fetchMetadata()` is trying reach metadata at `https://<ourserver>/v1/Metadata` and not at where it is available `https://<ourserver>/v1/$metadata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Breeze that you are using OData, by default it assumes WebApi. So:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
```

Also see: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata